# Java DO WHILE loop with phone numbers

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

I created a simple program that will ask the user for the last 7 digits of their phone number. I used a do - while loop, but I realized that if the user types in a digit starting with '0' the program will not count that as a 1st digit. What do I do? This is what I have so far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneCode {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 
  
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        int phoneNum;

        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter your 305 phone number: ");
            phoneNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        } while (phoneNum <= 1000000 || phoneNum >= 9999999);
        System.out.print(phoneNum);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why 0 is not counted as a first digit is that Java truncates any number that starts with 0 to the first non-zero place, and in your code, any seven digit number that starts with 0 would be truncated to the first non-zero digits place, which would be less than 7 digits long. For example, the number `00001` is parsed as `1`, as they both represent the same value. Anyways, consider using a `String` to store the number, as you can maintain the leading zeros and easily check for the correct length.
Also, consider using a true value for your do-while loop and break out of the loop when the correct value is entered.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter the last 7 digits of your phone number: ");
        String phoneNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (phoneNumber.length() == 7) {
            System.out.println("Your phone number is: " + phoneNumber);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid phone number. Please try again.");
        }
    } while (true);
```